# sencha-touch : manage a list of items with checkboxes in a form

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, extjs4

I have a list of languages linked to user preferences. (I know how can I retrieve the list by json).

Do you a how can I display/manage a form with all languages selected or not with checkboxes in sencha-touch?

I want to have a form with list of languages where each line has a checkbox and the name of the language.

Answer (score 0):

I have been also investigating on that for a while and I found my own solution for the problem. I just add every items programmatically by iterating the store data while the page is onRender event. here is the sample code.

```
 var catStore = Ext.getStore('categorystore');
 for (i = 0; i < catStore.getCount(); i++) {
     this.add({
                 xtype: 'rating',
                 store:   'categorystore',
                 itemsCount : 5,
                 minValue:   -1,
                 value:   2,
                 name: catStore.getAt(i).data.categoryId,
                 label: catStore.getAt(i).data.name,
                 inputCls : 'x-rating-star-input',
                 itemCls : 'x-rating-star',
                 itemHoverCls : 'x-rating-star-hover'
     }); 
}
```

Comment: please put this onRender event of the container component and you can add what ever component items. I have used here a custom component 'rating'. that is it. if it helps!